# audiocontext not producing any sound

Tags: javascript, audiocontext

I am trying to get my feet wet with `AudioContext` and so far I am not able to get a single sound to play.

here is my simple example

```
var context = new AudioContext()
var o = context.createOscillator()
o.type = "sine"
o.connect(context.destination)
o.start()
```

From everything I have seen, this should work, but I am not getting any sound.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you open your web console? Don't you have a warning saying something like *The audiocontext was blocked because there wasn't any user interaction*?

Comment: thanks! I had warning off and only errors and info on in my console, that was indeed the issue!